# Error when using pytorch num_workers in colab. when num_workers > 0

Tags: python, pytorch

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

= True

and i running code this because don't use this, an error occurs.

torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')

and

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.trainList = []
        self.base_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data_set/all_train_data/"

        with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/data_set/example.json', 'r') as f:
            jsonFile = json.load(f)
            for i in jsonFile:
              self.trainList = jsonFile[i][0]

        self.training = glob.glob(base_path+str('*.mp4'))
    
    def __len__(self):
        #return len(self.trainList)
        return len(self.training)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        #self.fileName = self.trainList[idx]
        self.fileName = self.training[idx]
        #self.filePath =  self.base_path + str(self.fileName)
        self.filePath = self.fileName
        print(self.fileName)
        feature, save = makeFeature(self.filePath, self.fileName)
        if save:
            return feature, self.fileName
        else:
            return False, False
```

```
dataset = CustomDataset()
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=9, shuffle=False,num_workers = 1)
```

then error occur with this massage

exited unexpectedly with exit code 1. Details are lost due to multiprocessing. Rerunning with num_workers=0 may give better error trace.

how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried re-running with `num_workers=0` as the message suggests?

Comment: yes i use num_workers = 0 it works. 

But isn't it faster to increase the value of num_workers?

Comment: Have you checked how many cpu cores are available to use on colab?

Comment: yes 12 core. because i use colab pro+